# Enviar multiples objetos con archivos en un array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formdata, angular12

Estoy tratando de conseguir la siguiente estructura de datos desde un formulario Reactivo de Angular:

```
{
  files: [
    {
      name: string,
      file: blob,
    },
    {
      name: string,
      file: blob,
    },

     ...
  ]
}
```

Necesito enviar al backend un objeto con una única propiedad `files`, que es un array de objetos, y cada uno de esos objetos contiene una propiedad `file` que tendrá como valor un archivo...

El input en el HTML:

```html
<form [formGroup]="formAnexos" (ngSubmit)="saveAnexos()">
    <input type="file" formControlName="anexo" (change)="onFileChange($event)" />
</form>
```

(Es el mismo input para cargar varios archivos)

---

El componente .ts:

En el .TS voy asignando los archivos a un objeto (`itemsObject`), que luego almaceno en un array: `arrayDatos`

```js
export class AnexosComponent implements OnInit {
  
    arrayDatos: any[] = [];
    itemsObject: any = {
        name: '',
        file: <any>File,
    }

    ngOnInit(): void { }

    get frm() {
        return this.formAnexos.controls;
    }

    onFileChange(event: any): void {
    
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
        
             let file: File = event.target.files[0];
             
             this.itemsObject.name = file.name;
             this.itemsObject.file = file;

             this.arrayDatos.push({ ...this.itemsObject });
        }
    }


    saveAnexos(): void {
    
       const formData:FormData = new FormData();
      
       formData.append('files', this.arrayDatos);

       this.fileService.saveData(formData).subscribe( (data) => {
           // ...
       });
    
    }
}
```

El gran problema es, al enviar los datos, pasa el nombre, pero no pasa ningún archivo... la propiedad `file` va vacía

No sé si es al momento de añadirlos en el FormData que el archivo desaparece, o al agregarlo en el array.. (`this.arrayDatos.push({ ...this.itemsObject })`)

Gracias de antemano por cualquier sugerencia!

Comment: Esa estructura es la estructura por defecto que de hecho te mandaria un formulario a un backend, pero tienes que tener en cuenta que dependiendo del backend que utilices (no se si utilices PHP por ej), cuando tu envias archivos y los envias de manera correcta, los archivos **JAMAS** van a mostrarse o guardarse en las variables `$_POST` o `$_GET`, estaran en una variable `$_FILES`, ahora, si no usas PHP, seria bueno que especificaras cual es el back que usas, otro punto importante es que si van a ser varios archivos entonces deberias colocar el attr `enctype='multipart/form-data'` en el form.

Comment: Y tambien el atributo `multiple` en el `input file`, entonces en un lado por ejemplo en `$_POST` o `$_GET` recibes informacion que no sean archivos y en `$_FILES` recibes los archivos con su informacion.